# django update using logged in username as pk

Tags: django

So I made table and post method menus with logged user information. I want to update information using username. If there's no username exit on table as logged in user, it posts data but if username already exits, I want it to overwrite data. So far, it doesn't overwrite but just post. What can I do to fix this?

model.py

```
   class OrderItem(models.Model):
    
        username = models.CharField('Username', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
        first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
        vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        menu_name = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        note = models.CharField('note', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

view.py

```
 def OrderView(request):
        form = OrderForm()
    
        context = {'form': form}
        if request.method == 'POST':
    
            form1 = OrderForm(request.POST)
            print(request.POST)
            if form1.is_valid():
                form1.save()
    
                return redirect('order-page')
        return render(request, '/order_info.html', context)
    
 def UpdateOrderView(request, pk):
     username = user.is_authenticated
     order = OrderItem.objects.get(username=username)
     form1 = OrderForm()
        
     context = {'form1': form1 }
        
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form1 = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
         print(request.POST)
         if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
        
            return redirect('order-update', pk=pk)
     return render(request, '/order_info.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("order_info", views.OrderView, name="order-page"),
    path("<int:pk>", views.UpdateOrderView, name="order-update"),
  
]
```

Comment: "I want it to overwrite data. So far, it doesn't overwrite but just post." Can you explain it a little, please? It's not clear.

Comment: means, it just post and post. instead of overwriting update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update this in your `models.py`

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField('Username', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, primary_key=True)
```

If the above solution not work try to remove the migration and `python manage.py makemigrations` again

Comment: not working. if I do this. it posts but data in db doesn't get overwrited for update